# Default video preview for Custom Camera App?

Tags: android, camera

I created preview class that must be passed to the Camera object before the live **image preview** ...I tried it and it's working...how can I use it default for **video Preview.**.

any suggestion here?

Answer (score 1):

Either call `setCamera()` on the `MediaRecorder` (which will automatically use any preview surface set up for that `Camera`) or call `setPreviewDisplay()` on `MediaRecorder`, supplying your `SurfaceHolder`.

Comment: as u suggest call setCamera() for MediaRecorder...but I don't think so it's full HD disaply..I explicit call mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(width, height) also..but it's giving me cropping  view...any idea how to open VideoPreview in Full HD?

Comment: @Shubh: You need to set the preview size and you need to set an appropriate size for the preview surface (same aspect ratio). Whether "Full HD" is a valid preview size for your device, I cannot say.